# Convert String field to an Encoded String in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregation

My requirement is to write a Mongo aggregation which returns a List of "virtual" Documents by grouping some existing "actual" Documents from the collection.

I intend to use this result as-is on my UI project, I'm looking for ways I can add a unique and decodable ID to it during the aggregation itself.

Example:

```
[   
    {... pipeline stages},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                bookCode: '$bookCode',
                bookName: '$bookName'
            }
            books: {
                $push: '$bookId'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            //virtual unique Id by combining bookCode and bookName
            virtualId: {
                $concat: [
                    {
                        $ifNull: [ '$_id.bookCode', '~' ]
                    },
                    '-',
                    {
                        $ifNull: [ '$_id.bookName', '~' ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            books: '$books'
        }
    }
]
```

Sample Output:

```
[
    {
        virtualId: 'BC01-BOOKNAME01'
        books: ['BID01', 'BID02']
    },
    {
        virtualId: 'BC02-BOOKNAME01'
        books: ['BID03', 'BID04']
    },
    {
        virtualId: '~-BOOKNAME01'
        books: ['BID05', 'BID06']
    },
    {
        virtualId: 'BC02-~'
        books: ['BID07', 'BID08']
    },
    {
        virtualId: '~-~'
        books: ['BID09', 'BID10']
    },
]
```

This method of concatenating grouping fields to generate `virtualId` works, but is there a way to make it more terse?
Perhaps some way I could convert this to an unreadable by human but decodable format.

TLDR: I'm looking for ways to create an ID for each result document in the aggregation query itself, that would give back it's contributing fields if I decode it later.
MongoDB Version: 4.0.0

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: @mohammadNaimi, I've added a sample output. Hope it helps.

Comment: do you want code id as base64 or some thing like this ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi, yes that would work, I've been trying to find an example to do so but couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

use this aggregation we use funtion and generate code with js function

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      books: 1,
      virtualId: {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(a){var t = '';for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){t=a.charCodeAt(i)+t;};return t;}",
          "args": [
            "$virtualId"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lm_VjIG54BG

Comment: This would work on mongodb 4.4+. Is there a way to do something similar for v4.0.0?